# How to improve the label placement in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, plot-annotations

I use matplotlib to plot a scatter chart:

[image]

And label the bubble using a transparent box according to the tip at [How to annotate point on a scatter automatically placed arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074996/7758804)

Here is the code:

```
if show_annote:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        annote_text = annotes[i][0][0]  # STK_ID
        ax.annotate(annote_text, xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(-10,3),
            textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.2),
            fontproperties=ANNOTE_FONT)
```

and the resulting plot:
[image]

But there is still room for improvement to reduce overlap (for instance the label box offset is fixed as (-10,3)). Are there algorithms that can:

1. dynamically change the offset of label box according to the crowdedness of its neighbourhood
2. dynamically place the label box remotely and add an arrow line beween bubble and label box
3. somewhat change the label orientation
4. label_box overlapping bubble is better than label_box overlapping label_box?

I just want to make the chart easy for human eyes to comprehand, so some overlap is OK, not as rigid a constraint as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement suggests. And the bubble quantity within the chart is less than 150 most of the time.

I find the so called `Force-based label placement` http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729  is quite interesting. I don't know if there is any python code/package available to implement the algorithm.

I am not an academic guy and not looking for an optimum solution, and my python codes need to label many charts, so the speed/memory is in the scope of consideration.

Answer (score 29):

Another option using my library `adjustText`, written specially for this purpose (https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText).

```
from adjustText import adjust_text
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 50
scatter_data = np.random.rand(N, 3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1],
           c=scatter_data[:, 2], s=scatter_data[:, 2] * 150)
labels = ['ano_{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
texts = []
for x, y, text in zip(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1], labels):
    texts.append(ax.text(x, y, text))
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 50
scatter_data = np.random.rand(N, 3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1],
           c=scatter_data[:, 2], s=scatter_data[:, 2] * 150)
labels = ['ano_{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
texts = []
for x, y, text in zip(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1], labels):
    texts.append(ax.text(x, y, text))
adjust_text(texts, force_text=0.05, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>",
                                                    color='r', alpha=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

It doesn't repel from the bubbles, only from their centers and other texts.

Comment: To whom it may concern... I had a plot with around 200 labels and the default settings lead to long render times. Set parameter `lim=20` i.e. to quickly iterate (default is 500). Supercool tool btw! Thanks very much for making this available.

Answer (score 28):

The following builds on [tcaswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859652/190597).

Networkx layout methods such as `nx.spring_layout` rescale the positions so that they all fit in a unit square (by default). Even the position of the fixed `data_nodes` are rescaled. So, to apply the `pos` to the original `scatter_data`, an unshifting and unscaling must be performed.

Note also that `nx.spring_layout` has a `k` parameter which controls the optimal distance between nodes. As `k` increases, so does the distance of the annotations from the data points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 20
scatter_data = np.random.rand(N, 3)*10


def repel_labels(ax, x, y, labels, k=0.01):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    data_nodes = []
    init_pos = {}
    for xi, yi, label in zip(x, y, labels):
        data_str = 'data_{0}'.format(label)
        G.add_node(data_str)
        G.add_node(label)
        G.add_edge(label, data_str)
        data_nodes.append(data_str)
        init_pos[data_str] = (xi, yi)
        init_pos[label] = (xi, yi)

    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=init_pos, fixed=data_nodes, k=k)

    # undo spring_layout's rescaling
    pos_after = np.vstack([pos[d] for d in data_nodes])
    pos_before = np.vstack([init_pos[d] for d in data_nodes])
    scale, shift_x = np.polyfit(pos_after[:,0], pos_before[:,0], 1)
    scale, shift_y = np.polyfit(pos_after[:,1], pos_before[:,1], 1)
    shift = np.array([shift_x, shift_y])
    for key, val in pos.items():
        pos[key] = (val*scale) + shift

    for label, data_str in G.edges():
        ax.annotate(label,
                    xy=pos[data_str], xycoords='data',
                    xytext=pos[label], textcoords='data',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                                    shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0,
                                    connectionstyle="arc3", 
                                    color='red'), )
    # expand limits
    all_pos = np.vstack(pos.values())
    x_span, y_span = np.ptp(all_pos, axis=0)
    mins = np.min(all_pos-x_span*0.15, 0)
    maxs = np.max(all_pos+y_span*0.15, 0)
    ax.set_xlim([mins[0], maxs[0]])
    ax.set_ylim([mins[1], maxs[1]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1],
           c=scatter_data[:, 2], s=scatter_data[:, 2] * 150)
labels = ['ano_{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
repel_labels(ax, scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1], labels, k=0.008)

plt.show()
```

with `k=0.011` yields

[image]
and with `k=0.008` yields
[image]

Comment: I had to change pos.iteritems() in the for loop to pos.items().  I'm using Python 3.5.2 and networkx v1.11.

Comment: I am getting `FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
  all_pos = np.vstack(pos.values())` Could you please advise how that can be resolved?

Answer (score 22):

It is a little rough around the edges (I can't quite figure out how to scale the relative strengths of the spring network vs the repulsive force, and the bounding box is a bit screwed up), but this is a decent start:

```
import networkx as nx

N = 15
scatter_data = rand(3, N)
G=nx.Graph()

data_nodes = []
init_pos = {}
for j, b in enumerate(scatter_data.T):
    x, y, _ = b
    data_str = 'data_{0}'.format(j)
    ano_str = 'ano_{0}'.format(j)
    G.add_node(data_str)
    G.add_node(ano_str)
    G.add_edge(data_str, ano_str)
    data_nodes.append(data_str)
    init_pos[data_str] = (x, y)
    init_pos[ano_str] = (x, y)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=init_pos, fixed=data_nodes)
ax = gca()
ax.scatter(scatter_data[0], scatter_data[1], c=scatter_data[2], s=scatter_data[2]*150)

for j in range(N):
    data_str = 'data_{0}'.format(j)
    ano_str = 'ano_{0}'.format(j)
    ax.annotate(ano_str,
                xy=pos[data_str], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[ano_str], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                                connectionstyle="arc3"))

all_pos = np.vstack(pos.values())
mins = np.min(all_pos, 0)
maxs = np.max(all_pos, 0)

ax.set_xlim([mins[0], maxs[0]])
ax.set_ylim([mins[1], maxs[1]])

draw()
```

[image: sample image]

How well it works depends a bit on how your data is clustered.

Answer (score 2):

Just created another quick solution that is also very fast: [textalloc](https://github.com/ckjellson/textalloc)

In this case you could do something like this:

```
import textalloc as ta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2022)
N = 30
scatter_data = np.random.rand(N, 3)*10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(scatter_data[:, 0], scatter_data[:, 1], c=scatter_data[:, 2], s=scatter_data[:, 2] * 50, zorder=10,alpha=0.5)
labels = ['ano-{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
text_list = labels = ['ano-{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
ta.allocate_text(fig,ax,scatter_data[:, 0],scatter_data[:, 1],
            text_list,
            x_scatter=scatter_data[:, 0], y_scatter=scatter_data[:, 1],
            max_distance=0.2,
            min_distance=0.04,
            margin=0.039,
            linewidth=0.5,
            nbr_candidates=400)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot]

Answer (score 0):

We can use plotly for this. But we can't help placing overlap correctly if there is lot of data. Instead we can zoom in and zoom out.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007 and continent=='Americas'")


fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", text="country", log_x=True, size_max=100, color="lifeExp",
                 title="Life Expectency")
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]