# Matplotlib to generate such circular plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

does anyone know if it's possible to generate such plots in matplotlib?
the image is taken from the following [page](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/04/data-science-of-the-facebook-world/).  If not, there another 'python' solution to generate such plots?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the packange [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.io/) which will take care of the layout and plotting (via matplotlib if you want).

Comment: do you know if arrows can be drawn as well using the networkx/matplotlib?  http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.0rc1/examples/drawing/node_colormap.html

Comment: If it isn't built in, it is easy to do with annotate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938541/how-to-improve-the-label-placement-for-matplotlib-scatter-chart-code-algorithm/15859652#15859652 for how to get the node locations out of a network.