# How to fix overlapping annotations / text

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I'm trying to stop annotation text overlapping in my graphs. The method suggested in the accepted answer to [Matplotlib overlapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850142/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations) looks extremely promising, however is for bar graphs. I'm having trouble converting the "axis" methods over to what I want to do, and I don't understand how the text lines up.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# start new plot
plt.clf()
plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")

together = [(0, 1.0, 0.4), (25, 1.0127692669427917, 0.41), (50, 1.016404709797609, 0.41), (75, 1.1043426359673716, 0.42), (100, 1.1610446924342996, 0.44), (125, 1.1685687930691457, 0.43), (150, 1.3486407784550272, 0.45), (250, 1.4013999168008104, 0.45)]
together.sort()

for x,y,z in together:
    plt.annotate(str(x), xy=(y, z), size=8)

eucs = [y for (x,y,z) in together]
covers = [z for (x,y,z) in together]

p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Images (if this works) can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vRbv.png) (this code):

[image: image1]

and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NVbP.png) (more complicated):

[image: image2]

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938541/how-to-improve-the-label-placement-for-matplotlib-scatter-chart-code-algorithm/15859652#15859652

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I just wanted to post here another solution, a small library I wrote to implement this kind of things: https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText
An example of the process can be seen here:
[image]

Here is the example image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
import numpy as np
together = [(0, 1.0, 0.4), (25, 1.0127692669427917, 0.41), (50, 1.016404709797609, 0.41), (75, 1.1043426359673716, 0.42), (100, 1.1610446924342996, 0.44), (125, 1.1685687930691457, 0.43), (150, 1.3486407784550272, 0.45), (250, 1.4013999168008104, 0.45)]
together.sort()

text = [x for (x,y,z) in together]
eucs = [y for (x,y,z) in together]
covers = [z for (x,y,z) in together]

p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)
texts = []
for x, y, s in zip(eucs, covers, text):
    texts.append(plt.text(x, y, s))

plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")
adjust_text(texts, only_move={'points':'y', 'texts':'y'}, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want a perfect figure, you can fiddle around a little. First, let's also make text repel the lines - for that we just create lots of virtual points along them using scipy.interpolate.interp1d.

We want to avoid moving the labels along the x-axis, because, well, why not do it for illustrative purposes. For that we use the parameter `only_move={'points':'y', 'text':'y'}`. If we want to move them along x axis only in the case that they are overlapping with text, use `move_only={'points':'y', 'text':'xy'}`. Also in the beginning the function chooses optimal alignment of texts relative to their original points, so we only want that to happen along the y axis too, hence `autoalign='y'`. We also reduce the repelling force from points to avoid text flying too far away due to our artificial avoidance of lines. All together:

```
from scipy import interpolate
p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)
texts = []
for x, y, s in zip(eucs, covers, text):
    texts.append(plt.text(x, y, s))

f = interpolate.interp1d(eucs, covers)
x = np.arange(min(eucs), max(eucs), 0.0005)
y = f(x)    
    
plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")
adjust_text(texts, x=x, y=y, autoalign='y',
            only_move={'points':'y', 'text':'y'}, force_points=0.15,
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work Phlya! You could probably also add this answer or something like it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074996/matplotlib-how-to-annotate-point-on-a-scatter-automatically-placed-arrow

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like it! There are a couple other questions on SO which are relevant, but I haven't seen that one... I'll try to find time to write an answer for it, but feel free to do so yourself if you want!

Comment: @Phlya: If I run your example I receive the following error: 'float' object has no attribute 'get_position' . Removing the line with adjust_text it works fine. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: @Phlya: Following your examples at GitHub it works now, looks really splendid! Since others may find your package first visiting SO, I would advice you to update the answer and code.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I am glad it works well for you! Thanks for the advice, I think I will do this at some point...

Comment: Amazing library, thanks a lot! BTW, it works only if applying at once on ALL texts, it does not work inside a loop (eg: to replace one group after the other, it's not possible, you have to do all texts at once).

Comment: @gaborous ooops I missed your comment, sorry - what do you mean? It can work in a loop, but it only takes into account the objects that are given to the function...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen did you change the axes limits after calling adjust_text? That would be a problem, it should always be called in the very end.

Comment: Great package. I'm trying to use it for different subplots where I type `texts.append(ax2.text(oscmax/numerator, 100, label))
 texts.append(ax1.text(oscmax/numerator, 100, label))`. However, when I add `adjust_text(texts,color="C0",only_move={'points':'y'})` at the end, it puts all the text that should be in ax1 into ax2 (and lumps them together). From the examples in your manual page, it seems like it is possible to use it with axes, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi @Nigu, you should call it separately for each subplot, and specify `ax=ax1` or `ax=ax2`. Let me know whether this helps, otherwise please report an issue on github with a reproducible example.

Comment: And, obviously, they need to be in separate lists for each subplot.

Comment: @Phlya What a prompt response, thank you! Yes, it works perfectly well now. You're my savior.

Comment: If anyone get's the error `'str' object has no attribute 'values'`, please use `adjust_text(texts, only_move={'points':'y', 'texts':'y'}, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))` instead of the syntax in the answer. See https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText/issues/83

Comment: @Phiya, is there a way to wrap `annotate` like you do with `text`?

Comment: @garej sorry for a late reply - no, unfortunately, not. A lot of people are asking for that, and I understand the need, but I haven't figured out a way to do that (and don't have much time to work on the library now). Please feel free to look at the source code and contribute.

Answer (score 12):

**Easy solution here:** (for jupyter notebooks)

```
%matplotlib notebook
import mplcursors

plt.plot.scatter(y=YOUR_Y_DATA, x =YOUR_X_DATA)


mplcursors.cursor(multiple = True).connect(
    "add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(
          YOUR_ANOTATION_LIST[sel.target.index]
))
```

Right click on a dot to **show** its anotation.

Left click on an anotation to **close it**.

Right click and drag on an anotation to **move it**.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With a lot of fiddling, I figured it out. Again credit for the original solution goes to the answer for [Matplotlib overlapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850142/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations) .

I don't however know how to find the exact width and height of the text. If someone knows, please post an improvement (or add a comment with the method).

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_text_positions(text, x_data, y_data, txt_width, txt_height):
    a = zip(y_data, x_data)
    text_positions = list(y_data)
    for index, (y, x) in enumerate(a):
        local_text_positions = [i for i in a if i[0] > (y - txt_height) 
                            and (abs(i[1] - x) < txt_width * 2) and i != (y,x)]
        if local_text_positions:
            sorted_ltp = sorted(local_text_positions)
            if abs(sorted_ltp[0][0] - y) < txt_height: #True == collision
                differ = np.diff(sorted_ltp, axis=0)
                a[index] = (sorted_ltp[-1][0] + txt_height, a[index][1])
                text_positions[index] = sorted_ltp[-1][0] + txt_height*1.01
                for k, (j, m) in enumerate(differ):
                    #j is the vertical distance between words
                    if j > txt_height * 2: #if True then room to fit a word in
                        a[index] = (sorted_ltp[k][0] + txt_height, a[index][1])
                        text_positions[index] = sorted_ltp[k][0] + txt_height
                        break
    return text_positions

def text_plotter(text, x_data, y_data, text_positions, txt_width,txt_height):
    for z,x,y,t in zip(text, x_data, y_data, text_positions):
        plt.annotate(str(z), xy=(x-txt_width/2, t), size=12)
        if y != t:
            plt.arrow(x, t,0,y-t, color='red',alpha=0.3, width=txt_width*0.1, 
                head_width=txt_width, head_length=txt_height*0.5, 
                zorder=0,length_includes_head=True)

# start new plot
plt.clf()
plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")

together = [(0, 1.0, 0.4), (25, 1.0127692669427917, 0.41), (50, 1.016404709797609, 0.41), (75, 1.1043426359673716, 0.42), (100, 1.1610446924342996, 0.44), (125, 1.1685687930691457, 0.43), (150, 1.3486407784550272, 0.45), (250, 1.4013999168008104, 0.45)]
together.sort()

text = [x for (x,y,z) in together]
eucs = [y for (x,y,z) in together]
covers = [z for (x,y,z) in together]

p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)

txt_height = 0.0037*(plt.ylim()[1] - plt.ylim()[0])
txt_width = 0.018*(plt.xlim()[1] - plt.xlim()[0])

text_positions = get_text_positions(text, eucs, covers, txt_width, txt_height)

text_plotter(text, eucs, covers, text_positions, txt_width, txt_height)

plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Creates https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiTeU.png
[image]

The more complicated graph is now https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJeYW.png, still a bit iffy but much better!
[image]

Comment: and `get_window_extent()` is the artist function that you want

Comment: annotation.get_window_extent() returns Bbox(array([[ 349.194625,  38.0572  ], [ 372.132125,  448.0572  ]])). What does this imply about the width/height of the text?

Comment: That is the bounding box of the text in display units. See http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882249/matplotlib-aligning-y-ticks-to-the-left/15883858#15883858

Comment: this code is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10739207/854988, right? – i think would be nice to credit the original author, @fraxel

Comment: It seems that `a[index][2]` should be replaced by `a[index][1]` in `get_text_positions`. Elements in `a` indeed look to be tuples of size 2. The code doesn't break with the provided example because the concerned part is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a package for problems like this: [textalloc](https://github.com/ckjellson/textalloc)

The following example shows how you might use it in this case. With a few parameter tweaks you can generate a plot like this in a fraction of a second:

```
import textalloc as ta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
x_lines = [np.array([0.0, 0.03192317, 0.04101177, 0.26085659, 0.40261173, 0.42142198, 0.87160195, 1.00349979]) + np.random.normal(0,0.03,(8,)) for _ in range(4)]
y_lines = [np.array([0. , 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 1. , 1. ]) + np.random.normal(0,0.03,(8,)) for _ in range(4)]
text_lists = [['0', '25', '50', '75', '100', '125', '150', '250'] for _ in range(4)]

texts = []
for tl in text_lists:
    texts += tl
fig,ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
for x_line,y_line,text_list in zip(x_lines,y_lines,text_lists):
    ax.plot(x_line,y_line,color="black",linewidth=0.5)
ta.allocate_text(fig,ax,np.hstack(x_lines),np.hstack(y_lines),
            texts,
            x_lines=x_lines, y_lines=y_lines,
            max_distance=0.1,
            min_distance=0.025,
            margin=0.0,
            linewidth=0.5,
            nbr_candidates=400)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another solution I used in my code.

1. Get the y axis ticks and find the difference between any 2 consecutive ticks (y_diff).
2. Annotate first line by adding every "y" element of the graph to a list.
3. While annotating the second item, check if the annotation of the previous graph (prev_y) for same "x" falls in the same y axis tick range (curr_y).
4. Annotate only if (prev_y - curr_y) >  (y_diff /3) . You can divide the difference by number required by graph size and annotation font size.

```
 annotation_y_values = []
    for i, j in zip(x, df[df.columns[0]]):
        annotation_y_values.append(j)
        axs.annotate(str(j), xy=(i, j), color="black")
 count = 0
 y_ticks = axs.get_yticks()
 y_diff = y_ticks[-1] - y_ticks[-2]
 for i, j in zip(x, df1[df1.columns[0]]):
        df_annotate_value = annotation_y_values[count]
        current_y_val = j
        diff = df_annotate_value - current_y_val
        if diff > (y_diff/3):
            axs.annotate(str(j), xy=(i, j), color="black", size=8)
        count = count + 1
```