# Why aren't the overlapping annotations realigning themselves in the graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found some code on stack overflow about fixing overlapping annotations in matplotlib. I wanted to test it out, so I copied it into my own iPython notebook. However, when I ran it, it didn't have the same output.

The point of the code is to test if the annotations are overlapping, and if they are, they move so they aren't, and drop a red arrow to show the data point that they are describing. However, when I ran the code myself, this didn't happen.

I am using Python 3

Here is the original link: [Matplotlib overlapping annotations / text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073683/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations-text)

The code is shown below:

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_text_positions(text, x_data, y_data, txt_width, txt_height):
    a = zip(y_data, x_data)
    text_positions = list(y_data)
    for index, (y, x) in enumerate(a):
        local_text_positions = [i for i in a if i[0] > (y - txt_height) 
                            and (abs(i[1] - x) < txt_width * 2) and i != (y,x)]
        if local_text_positions:
            sorted_ltp = sorted(local_text_positions)
            if abs(sorted_ltp[0][0] - y) < txt_height: #True == collision
                differ = np.diff(sorted_ltp, axis=0)
                a[index] = (sorted_ltp[-1][0] + txt_height, a[index][1])
                text_positions[index] = sorted_ltp[-1][0] + txt_height*1.01
                for k, (j, m) in enumerate(differ):
                    #j is the vertical distance between words
                    if j > txt_height * 2: #if True then room to fit a word in
                        a[index] = (sorted_ltp[k][0] + txt_height, a[index][2])
                        text_positions[index] = sorted_ltp[k][0] + txt_height
                        break
    return text_positions

def text_plotter(text, x_data, y_data, text_positions, txt_width,txt_height):
    for z,x,y,t in zip(text, x_data, y_data, text_positions):
        plt.annotate(str(z), xy=(x-txt_width/2, t), size=12)
        if y != t:
            plt.arrow(x, t,0,y-t, color='red',alpha=0.3, width=txt_width*0.1, 
                head_width=txt_width, head_length=txt_height*0.5, 
                zorder=0,length_includes_head=True)

# start new plot
plt.clf()
plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")

together = [(0, 1.0, 0.4), (25, 1.0127692669427917, 0.41), (50, 1.016404709797609, 0.41), (75, 1.1043426359673716, 0.42), (100, 1.1610446924342996, 0.44), (125, 1.1685687930691457, 0.43), (150, 1.3486407784550272, 0.45), (250, 1.4013999168008104, 0.45)]
together.sort()

text = [x for (x,y,z) in together]
eucs = [y for (x,y,z) in together]
covers = [z for (x,y,z) in together]

p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)

txt_height = 0.0037*(plt.ylim()[1] - plt.ylim()[0])
txt_width = 0.018*(plt.xlim()[1] - plt.xlim()[0])

text_positions = get_text_positions(text, eucs, covers, txt_width, txt_height)

text_plotter(text, eucs, covers, text_positions, txt_width, txt_height)

plt.show()
```

This is what the output should look like:

[image: Arrows Showing/Annotations realigned]

This is what I get:

[image]

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Change font size of annotation texts to fit positions manually