# Attempting to plot images with annotations in matplotlib, but the overlap makes them unreadable

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts, annotations

I'm writing a script to classify images based on their features: Histogram, color balance, keypoint count, etc. And although the function that I wrote to display the charts works fine:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(15,7))

axes[0, 0].scatter((zip(*xy_a))[0], (zip(*xy_a))[1])
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[0, 0].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_a))[0][i],(zip(*xy_a))[1][i]))
axes[0, 0].set_title("xy_a")
axes[0, 0].set_xlabel('Histogram')
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('Average Pixel')

axes[1, 0].scatter(*zip(*xy_b))
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[1, 0].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_b))[0][i],(zip(*xy_b))[1][i]))
axes[1, 0].set_title("xy_b")
axes[1, 0].set_xlabel('Average Pixel')
axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('Keypoint Number')

axes[0, 1].scatter(*zip(*xy_c))
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[0, 1].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_c))[0][i],(zip(*xy_c))[1][i]))
axes[0, 1].set_title("xy_c")
axes[0, 1].set_xlabel('Keypoint Number')
axes[0, 1].set_ylabel('Histogram')

axes[1, 1].scatter(*zip(*xy_d))
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[1, 1].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_d))[0][i],(zip(*xy_d))[1][i]))
axes[1, 1].set_title("xy_d")
axes[1, 1].set_xlabel('Dimentional Mean')
axes[1, 1].set_ylabel('Histogram')

axes[0, 2].scatter(*zip(*xy_e))
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[0, 2].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_e))[0][i],(zip(*xy_f))[1][i]))
axes[0, 2].set_title("xy_e")
axes[0, 2].set_xlabel('Average Pixel')
axes[0, 2].set_ylabel('Dimentional Mean')

axes[1, 2].scatter(*zip(*xy_f))
for i, txt in enumerate(xy_na): axes[1, 2].annotate(txt, ((zip(*xy_f))[0][i],(zip(*xy_f))[1][i]))
axes[1, 2].set_title("xy_f")
axes[1, 2].set_xlabel('Keypoint Number')
axes[1, 2].set_ylabel('Dimentional Mean')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.suptitle("Folder: {}".format ((str(folder_path)).split("/")[-1]))

plt.show()
```

The chart that it generates is less than readable:

[image]

That folder has 13 images in it: 11 facial shots and 2 group pictures. Now, it's not *entirely unreadable*, but what happens when I run it on a folder with 100 images?

There are other answers on overlapping annotations, but none of them are applicable to my one-liner annotation scheme. If anyone could find a solution to my problem, that would be great.

Comment: Maybe you need to physically separate the points. Here is the logic I would use: sort on x and y points, if x_prev_pt - x_current_pt <= 1.5*text_pt_size, then shift the annotations x by the difference, similarly for y. I know how to do this in pandas, but unfortunately I am not able to glean your the structure of your data...

Comment: They're all just lists: `xy_a = [], xy_b = [], xy_c = [], xy_d = [], xy_e = [], xy_f = [], xy_na = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that, instead of showing all annotations at all time, just show the annotation when you click on a data point. The same data point could also be highlighted in the other subplots.

See [this cookbook recipe](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Interactive_Plotting.html) for an example on how to achieve this

Comment: Huh. Neat. But what if I want to save the chart?

Comment: hmm yeah, that wouldn't work then... Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073683/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations-text