# Show text annotations only above the line, not below

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I'm trying to get the text annotations in this line graph in matplotlib to show up above the line. I'm using the `adjustText` library to repel text from the line, but as seen in the image, some of the text is below the line. I based my code on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762716/4237080).

How can I get each annotation to appear above the line, connected to its point by a gray line? Some of them already are like this, but others are not.

```
x = list(df_usa['date'][61:-1].str.slice(5,)) # strings
x_range = np.arange(0, len(x))
y = list(df_usa['growth_factor'][61:-1])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
plt.plot(x, y, color="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x), 5))

texts = [plt.text(x_range[i], y[i], round(y[i], 2)) for i in range(len(x))]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x_range, y)
f_x = np.arange(min(x_range), max(x_range), 0.005)
f_y = f(f_x)

# Generate non-overlapping data point labels
adjust_text(texts, x=f_x, y=f_y,
            only_move={'points': 'y', 'text': 'y'},
            force_points=0.15,
            autoalign='y',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="gray", lw=0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach "prohibits" the points along the curve. An extension could be to also prohibit a band of points below the curve.

As your post doesn't seem to contain test data, here is an adaption of the example of the linked post:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

together = [(0, 1.0, 0.4), (25, 1.0127692669427917, 0.41), (50, 1.016404709797609, 0.41), (75, 1.1043426359673716, 0.42), (100, 1.1610446924342996, 0.44), (125, 1.1685687930691457, 0.43), (150, 1.3486407784550272, 0.45), (250, 1.4013999168008104, 0.45)]
together.sort()

text = [x for (x,y,z) in together]
eucs = [y for (x,y,z) in together]
covers = [z for (x,y,z) in together]

p1 = plt.plot(eucs,covers,color="black", alpha=0.5)
y0, y1 = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(y0, y1+.1*(y1-y0))
texts = []
for x, y, s in zip(eucs, covers, text):
    texts.append(plt.text(x, y, s))

f = interpolate.interp1d(eucs, covers)
x = np.arange(min(eucs), max(eucs), 0.0005)
y = f(x)

# optionally show the band of "forbidden" points
# plt.scatter(x=np.tile(x, 5), y=np.concatenate([y-eps for eps in np.linspace(0, 0.01, 5) ]), alpha=.1)

plt.xlabel("Proportional Euclidean Distance")
plt.ylabel("Percentage Timewindows Attended")
plt.title("Test plot")
adjust_text(texts, x=np.tile(x, 5), y=np.concatenate([y-eps for eps in np.linspace(0, 0.01, 5) ]), autoalign='y',
            only_move={'points':'y', 'text':'y'}, force_points=.3,
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]