# Add label at each step of cumulative bar plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, label

How can I add labels to each step of this cumulative step function as shown in the attached screenshot?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": range(1990, 2020, 4), "name": list("abcdefgh")})
df.year.hist(cumulative=True)
```

[image]

Comment: @JohanC The label indicates which item it was that increased the cumulation.

Comment: A specific example could be a list of EV charging stations in a region and when they opened. The plot is supposed to show the total number of available stations over time and display and some type of charging station identifier above each step in the function to make it clear which station newly opened at that point in time.

Comment: You're right, a histogram isn't what I want here. It just looks similar.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, but you might get what you need from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19073683/6692898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the generated bars. Their x coordinate and width tell where they are located in the x-axis. The bar height gives the y value for the label.  The positions on the x-axis will give a range that can be selected from the corresponding column of the dataframe.  For the x-position of the label, the corresponding year can be used.

Some care needs to be taken, as the last value could fall outside the official range of the last bar. Also, increasing the y margin helps to fit all text into the plot.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': range(1990, 2020, 4), 'name': [*'abcdefgh']})
ax = df.year.hist(cumulative=True)

for rect in ax.patches:
    left = rect.get_x()
    right = left + rect.get_width()
    height = rect.get_height()
    if rect == ax.patches[-1]: # make sure the last range is wide enough to include the last date
        right += 1
    df2 = df[(df['year'] >= left) &  (df['year'] <= right)]
    for year, name in zip(df2['year'], df2['name']):
        ax.text(year, height, f'{name}\n', ha='left', va='center')
ax.margins(y=0.15) # we need more room for the last label
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To only write one label per bar, you could add a `break` in the `for` loop:

```
    for year, name in zip(df2['year'], df2['name']):
        ax.text(year, height, f'{name}\n', ha='left', va='center')
        break
```

For the step plot, you could use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': range(1990, 2020, 4), 'name': [*'abcdefgh']})
ax = df.reset_index().plot(x='year', y='index', drawstyle="steps", legend=False)

for ind, (year, name) in enumerate(zip(df['year'], df['name'])):
    ax.text(year, ind, f' {name}', ha='left', va='center')
```

[image: example step plot]

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I should have used instead of `df.hist`: `df.reset_index().plot(x='year', y='index', drawstyle="steps")`.