# Annotating scatterplot points with DF column text Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm struggling annotating plots at the minute.
I've come from R so I'm used to the ease of being able to annotate scatterplot points with minimum code.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl
```

```
url = ('https://fbref.com/en/share/nXtrf')
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df = df[['Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Unnamed: 2_level_0', 'Play', 'Perf']].copy()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df[['Player','Squad','Min','SoTA','Saves']]
df = df.drop([25])
df['Min'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Min'])
df['SoTA'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SoTA'])
df['Saves'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Saves'])
df['Min'] = df[df['Min'] > 1600]['Min']
df = df.dropna()
```

```
df.plot(x = 'Saves', y = 'SoTA', kind = "scatter")
```

I've tried numerous ways to annotate this plot. I'd like the points to be annotated with corresponding data from 'Player' column.

I've tried using a label_point function that I've found while trying to find a work around buy I keep getting Key Error 0 on most ways I try.

Any assistance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through both columns and [add a text](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) for each entry. Note that you need to save the `ax` returned by `df.plot(...)`.

```py
ax = df.plot(x='Saves', y='SoTA', kind="scatter")

for x, y, player in zip(df['Saves'], df['SoTA'], df['Player']):
    ax.text(x, y, f'{player}', ha='left', va='bottom')
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax + 0.15 * (xmax - xmin))  # some more margin to fit the texts
```

[image: example output]

An alternative is to use the [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to show an annotation while hovering (or after a click):

```py
import mplcursors

mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
```

[image: mplcursors example]

Comment: thanks for that, in the first example you gave me. That returns the x,y coordinates and pastes them as text. How would I replace the xy coordinates with text from the 'Players' column in the df?

Comment: To avoid overlapping texts, you could try [Matplotlib overlapping annotations / text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073683/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations-text).  That library can be installed as `pip install adjustText`.  Note that the mplcursor library also facilitates customizations such as showing a third column.