# Labels on seaborn timeseries chart

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data frame:

```
dates = [pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12:10:30'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12:10:35'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12:10:40')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ref_date': dates, 'x': [1, 3, 2]}).set_index('ref_date')
```

How do I add each x-value as text on the plot? If the x-axis weren't a time series, then I could have looped through each value and use `ax.text()`, but I don't know how to do that when I have timestamps instead, i.e. I don't know how to calculate the (x, y) coordinate for the text.

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df)
```

EDIT:
Is there a way we can dynamically make labels not overlap? For example, consider adding this extra point to the above `df`: `pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12:10:30.001')` and `1.03`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib (and Seaborn) uses the number of dates since the epoch to store date values. The function [date2num](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.2/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) can be used to convert datetime objects to this numeric representation:

```python
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.dates.date2num(pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12:10:30')))
#prints 14610.507291666667
```

To get the correct positions on the x axis for the text, this function can be used:

```python
sp = sns.scatterplot(data=df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sp.axes.text(matplotlib.dates.date2num(index), row['x'], row['x'], size='large')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @werner. Is there a way we can dynamically move the position of the label, especially when two labels are overlapping each other? Please see the EDIT above including an example.

Comment: There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19073683/2129801) about the overlapping problem. Maybe one of the answers can help you? If not I would suggest to ask a new question, as your edit abot the overlapping labels is a bit unrelated to the original question about the timeseries issue.